# Contentful CMS - getting image

Tags: javascript, json, api, content-management-system, contentful

How can I get each image for each entries. I have two array.
`items` and `includes`

ex: `items.fields.name = Mark`

How can I get the image associated to Mark?

Comment: Let's see the JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the HTTP REST API directly, you'll need to do the mappings yourself. For example, if you have an image in items[0].fields.image, that will contain an object with a sys property, with details about the kind of entity that is linked (asset or entry) and the id. Then you'll need to look for that in the includes array and match it.

If you use one of the [SDKs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/code/libraries/), that will be done automatically for you.

You can read more about Links here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/links/

Comment: I'm using the REST API directly, so I will try the SDK.

Thanks!